# What will twitter return in json if the twitter limit is exceeded?

Tags: twitter

I need to detect if twitter limit has been exceeded.  Is there something in the JSON response like a code or do I need to check the HttpResponse code?

Here is my URL:  http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android

Thanks

Comment: Include Java code to show others what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was thinking this question was not language specific so I killed the java tag.

Answer (score 6):

according to twitter API doc:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1, it does answer an 429 HTTP code, with:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 88,
      "message": "Rate limit exceeded"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can verify (empirically) that the return message is: {"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded","code":88}]}

Comment: how do you parse this?

Comment: what language are you using?